# Get Collections from object using reflection and getCount (.net 4)

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a requirement to reflect on a object get all properties that are collections and

1)GetCount for each collection

2)GetTotalCount (allCollectionCount)

3)Call a method with this collection.

Below is what I have done so far with a made up noddy structure for semplicity.
    I am stuck in how to call this method and how to get count for collection.

Any suggestions?

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                var request = GetDataRequest();

                //Get all properties 
                List<PropertyInfo> propInfoList =
                    new List<PropertyInfo>(request.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));

                //Get collections only
                var myClassCollections=propInfoList.Where(xxx => xxx.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof (IEnumerable))).ToList();

                var totalCountForAllCollections=????
                foreach (var col in myClassCollections)
                {
                    //How do I call my Method DoSomething
                    //      DoSomething<?>(col.?????)   
                }

            }

            public void DoSomething<T>(List<T> objectCollection)
            {
                //etc...
            }
            private static DataRequest GetDataRequest()
            {
                DataRequest request = new DataRequest();
                request.Addresses.Add(new Address
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    City = "London",
                    Postcode = "32131",
                    Street = "London Road"
                });
                request.Addresses.Add(new Address
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    City = "NewYork",
                    Postcode = "3432",
                    Street = "NewYork Road"
                });

                request.Customers.Add(new Customer
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Jo",
                    Surname = "Bloggs",
                });
                request.Customers.Add(new Customer
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Jon",
                    Surname = "Bloggs2",
                });
                request.Customers.Add(new Customer
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Jonny",
                    Surname = "Bloggs3",
                });
                return request;
            }
        }
        public class DataRequest
        {
            public DataRequest()
            {
                Customers = new List<Customer>();
                Orders = new List<Order>();
                Addresses = new List<Address>();

            }
            public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
            public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
            public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        }

        public class Customer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
        }

        public class Order
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string OrderNo { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Street { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string Postcode { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick and dirty, here you go...

```
// ..
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var request = GetDataRequest();

        //Get propertyValues for properties that are enumerable (i.e. lists,arrays etc)
        var collectionProperties = request.GetType()
                                          .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                          .Where(propertInfo => propertInfo.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x == typeof(IEnumerable)))
                                          .Select(p => p.GetValue(request, null))
                                          .Cast<IEnumerable<object>>().ToList();

        var totalCountForAllCollections = 0;
        // iterate through the list of propertyValues
        foreach (var collectionPropertyValue in collectionProperties)
        {
            totalCountForAllCollections += collectionPropertyValue.Count();
            collectionPropertyValue.DoSomething();
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("The total count for all collections is : {0}", totalCountForAllCollections);
        System.Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DoSomething<T>(this IEnumerable<T> objectCollection)
    {
        //etc...
        // N.B. you will have to use typeof(T) to implement logic specific to the type
        // If the logic in this method is non-specific to the typeof(T) then Implement logic accordingly
        System.Console.WriteLine("The type of the collection is: {0}", objectCollection.GetType());
        System.Console.WriteLine("The count of items in this collection is:{0}", objectCollection.Count());
    }
    // ..
}
// ..
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort .I see what you are doing and hopefully i cant make it work.currently "collectionProperties" does not compile " on select bit "value cannot be inferred same for getvalue

Comment: @developer9969 perhaps the difference is that my _Program_ class is **static** and yours isn't?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i just copied your code as whole and I get "no overload for method getvalue takes 1 argument".sorry to bother I will work it out.thanks

Comment: Assuming your properties aren't indexed (which they aren't), you can just pass _null_ for the second parameter of the _GetValue_ method. I've updated the same above. My project settings are set to .net4.5 by default which is why I didn't pick up the " no overload.." error. You should be able to copy, paste and run without problems this time.. If you're happy then please mark answer as accepted.